# How to find all complex solutions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

When i'm solving this Equation
$$z^{2018} + |z|^{1995}* \bar{z}^{83} = 2$$

I got this:
$$z_{k} = (cos(\frac{2\pi k}{1995}) + isin(\frac{2\pi k}{1995}) * \frac{1}{\sqrt[2018]{cos(\frac{4202\pi k}{1995})}}$$
$$k = 0 ... 1994$$
How to find all roots?

Comment: How exactly did you get this? From Wolfram Alpha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=re^{it}$

$$\implies2=r^{2018}(\cos2018t+i\sin2018t+\cos83t-i\sin83t)$$

Using  [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), $$\dfrac2{r^{2018}}=2\cos\dfrac{(2018+83)t}2\left(\cos\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2+i\sin\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2\right)$$

$\implies\sin\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2=0\implies\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2=m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

If $m$ is even, $=2n$(say),  $\implies\cos\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2=+1$

$$t=\dfrac{2n\pi}{1935},0\le2n<1935$$

$$\dfrac2{r^{2018}}=2\cos\dfrac{2101}2\cdot\dfrac{2n\pi}{1935}\implies r=?$$

What if $m$ is odd, $=2n+1$(say)  $\implies\cos\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2=-1$

Comment: what happens if cos(...) = -1?

Comment: @Yorn, Replace the values of $\cos$ & $\sin$ of  $$\dfrac{(2018-83)t}2$$

Comment: $$r = \frac{1}{\sqrt[2018]{cos(\frac{2101\pi n}{1995})}}$$

I found r, but I have a problem. I think r should be static